# Dividing sum of row by one multiindex column in pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I have a multi-index pivot table that looks like this when I export it to Excel:

```
                                   sum
                                  Amount
Type of Transaction      COGS     Revenue    Margin
Name             
Alex                      12        40         28
Ben                        6        25         19   
Dan                       10        30         20
```

I want it to include the margin percentage like this:

```
                                   sum
                                  Amount
Type of Transaction      COGS     Revenue    Margin    Margin%
Name             
Alex                      12        40         28         .7
Ben                        6        25         19         .76 
Dan                       10        30         20         .67
```

I got the Margin column by including "margins = True" when I created my pivot table.

I tried making a new column by dividing Margin by Revenue but I get

> KeyError: 'Revenue'

I tried doing this with:

```
graph["Margin%"] = graph["Margin"] / graph ["Revenue"]
```

Where graph is the name of my dataframe. I also tried using the div() function but I couldn't get it to work.

```
graph = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Name"], columns=["Type of Transaction"], aggfunc=[np.sum], margins = True)

graph = graph.rename(columns={"All":"Margin"})

graph["Margin%"] = graph["Margin"] / graph ["Revenue"]
```

Comment: Since it is a multiIndex pandas datafrane, can you paste the `df.to_dict()` ?

Comment: My dataframe is created from an excel sheet being imported. The one above is just an example one that I created

Comment: Hi Kamie, welcome to SO. As already asked by @harvpan it will be easier for us to help you if you can provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`. I'm sure you understand that could be pretty tedious to type it manually.

Comment: {('sum', 'Amount', 'COGS'): {'Alex': 12.0,'Ben': 6.0,'Dan': 10.0,'All': 28.0},('sum', 'Amount', 'Revenue'): {'Alex': 40.0, 
'Ben': 25.0,'Dan': 30.0,'All': 95.0},('sum', 'Amount', 'Margin'): {'Alex': 28.0,'Ben': 19.0,'Dan': 20.0,'All': 67.0}}